# how to use group by in mysql to get new string column

Tags: mysql

Basically my question is

```
  id  sid  string
    5    1    AAA
    6    1    BBB
    7    2    CCC
    8    3    ZZZ
    9    3    EEE
```

to get output like this

```
sid   str1   str2
1     AAA    BBB
```

where groupby sid

Comment: How many different `string` values are there?  If the number be bounded, than a simple pivot query should work.  If not, then you will need dynamic SQL.

Comment: only three string...

Comment: Your sample table alone shows five different `string` values.  Please clarify.

Comment: sorry but i want to use only 3 string give me query for 3 string alone...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pivot query:

```
SELECT t.sid,
    CASE WHEN t.str1 > 0 THEN 'AAA' ELSE NULL END AS str1,
    CASE WHEN t.str2 > 0 THEN 'BBB' ELSE NULL END AS str2,
    CASE WHEN t.str3 > 0 THEN 'CCC' ELSE NULL END AS str3
FROM
(
    SELECT t.sid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.string = 'AAA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS str1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.string = 'BBB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS str2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.string = 'CCC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS str3
    FROM yourTable t
    GROUP BY t.sid
) t
```

Comment: Please remove the last comma.

Comment: But my 3 strings are not default it may vary...example  it will come as abc or xyz or wss or anything else but for single sid i will get only random 3 strings

Comment: Do you mean three random _characters_ or three random _strings_ (i.e. collections of characters)?  If you don't know the string, then you will probably have to use dynamic SQL as a mentioned above.  Anyway, I will leave this up for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to create new columns on fly, if it's even possible, but you could get similar result with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
 SELECT sid, GROUP_CONCAT(`string` SEPARATOR ',') AS string_cols FROM t GROUP BY sid
```

Then in your application logic, you would need to split the `string_cols` by `SEPARATOR` into multiple fields.